# How to add title of element to class attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have seen that is it possible to transfer `title` attribute to class. The question is how to find the elements of the first word (animated) and assign them to the class title?

For example:

```
<div class="colelem" title="animated infinite bounce"></div>
<div class="colelem" title="animated infinite bounce"></div>
```

Add the class from the tittle to happen

```
<div class="colelem animated infinite bounce" title="animated infinite bounce"></div>
<div class="colelem animated infinite bounce" title="animated infinite bounce"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, however you can use the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass) method to add a class to an element

Comment: Might `$("#u211").addClass($("#u211").attr("title"))` do your work

Comment: One solution. But it is not suitable for mass use. Elements with the animation will be more, and we need to the class of tittle assign them automatically.

Comment: @НикитаСеверин See https://jsfiddle.net/vkmw7vb5/

Comment: Excellent, it works as intended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.addClass( function )`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to do this work.

```js
$(".colelem").addClass(function(){
    return $(this).attr("title");
});
```

```css
.animated { 
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colelem" title="animated infinite bounce">A</div>
<div class="colelem" title="animated infinite bounce">B</div>
<div class="colelem" title="animated infinite bounce">C</div>
```